# Gravity Forms - How to move radio input inside the label element

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm using WordPress Gravity Forms with their [Quiz Addon](https://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/quiz/), and I want to edit the HTML of the radio inputs of the Quiz answers.

This is what Gravity forms is currently rendering for each `li` element of the quiz answers:

```
<li class="gchoice_3_1_1">
    <input name="input_1" type="radio" value="gquiz1c4448d0c" checked="checked" id="choice_3_1_1" tabindex="2">
    <label for="choice_3_1_1" id="label_3_1_1" class="gquiz-correct-choice">Example label text
        <img class="gquiz-indicator" src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/gravityformsquiz-master/images/tick.png" alt="Correct response">
    </label>
</li>
```

This is what I want to achieve (move the `input` element into the `label` field):

```
<li class="gchoice_3_1_1">
    <label for="choice_3_1_1" id="label_3_1_1" class="gquiz-correct-choice">Example label text
        <input name="input_1" type="radio" value="gquiz1c4448d0c" checked="checked" id="choice_3_1_1" tabindex="2">
        <img class="gquiz-indicator" src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/gravityformsquiz-master/images/tick.png" alt="Correct response">
    </label>
</li>
```

And this is the PHP function I'm using inside the child themes `functions.php` to try and achieve it:

```
// move radio input inside label
add_filter("gform_field_choices", "radio_input_inside_label", 10, 2);
function radio_input_inside_label($choices, $field){
    if($field["type"] != "radio")
        return $choices;

    $choices = "";

    if(is_array($field["choices"])){
        $choice_id = 0;
        $count = 1;

        $logic_event = !empty($field["conditionalLogicFields"]) ? "onclick='gf_apply_rules(" . $field["formId"] . "," . GFCommon::json_encode($field["conditionalLogicFields"]) . ");'" : "";

        foreach($field["choices"] as $choice){
            $id = $field["id"] . '_' . $choice_id++;
            $field_value = !empty($choice["value"]) || rgar($field, "enableChoiceValue") ? $choice["value"] : $choice["text"];
            $checked = rgar($choice,"isSelected") ? "checked='checked'" : "";
            $tabindex = GFCommon::get_tabindex();

            $input = sprintf("<input name='input_%d' type='radio' value='%s' %s id='choice_%s' $tabindex $logic_event />", $field["id"], esc_attr($field_value), $checked, $id);
            $choices .= sprintf("<li class='gchoice_$id'><label for='choice_%s'>%s %s</label></li>", $id, $choice["text"], $input);

            $count++;
        }

    }

    return $choices;
}
```

This function is working for the standard Radio inputs, it moves the `input` inside the `label`. But it is not working for the Quiz radio inputs.

Can you see what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong field type selector.

If you want to move the radio input inside the label element for NORMAL gravity forms radio buttons, then this code will work:

```
// Gravity Forms Quiz - move radio input inside label
add_filter("gform_field_choices", "radio_input_inside_label", 10, 2);
function radio_input_inside_label($choices, $field){
    if($field["type"] != "radio")
        return $choices;

    $choices = "";

    if(is_array($field["choices"])){
        $choice_id = 0;
        $count = 1;

        $logic_event = !empty($field["conditionalLogicFields"]) ? "onclick='gf_apply_rules(" . $field["formId"] . "," . GFCommon::json_encode($field["conditionalLogicFields"]) . ");'" : "";

        foreach($field["choices"] as $choice){
            $id = $field["id"] . '_' . $choice_id++;
            $field_value = !empty($choice["value"]) || rgar($field, "enableChoiceValue") ? $choice["value"] : $choice["text"];
            $checked = rgar($choice,"isSelected") ? "checked='checked'" : "";
            $tabindex = GFCommon::get_tabindex();

            $input = sprintf("<input name='input_%d' type='radio' value='%s' %s id='choice_%s' $tabindex $logic_event />", $field["id"], esc_attr($field_value), $checked, $id);
            $choices .= sprintf("<li class='gchoice_$id'><label for='choice_%s'>%s %s</label></li>", $id, $input, $choice["text"]);

            $count++;
        }

    }

    return $choices;
}
```

But if you have the Gravity Forms Quiz Addon installed, and you want to move THOSE radio inputs inside the label, then this code is what you need. The only difference is that `if($field["type"] != "radio")` is replaced with `if($field["type"] != "quiz")`.

```
// Gravity Forms Quiz - move radio input inside label
add_filter("gform_field_choices", "radio_input_inside_label", 10, 2);
function radio_input_inside_label($choices, $field){
    if($field["type"] != "quiz") // <--- CHANGE HERE
        return $choices;

    $choices = "";

    if(is_array($field["choices"])){
        $choice_id = 0;
        $count = 1;

        $logic_event = !empty($field["conditionalLogicFields"]) ? "onclick='gf_apply_rules(" . $field["formId"] . "," . GFCommon::json_encode($field["conditionalLogicFields"]) . ");'" : "";

        foreach($field["choices"] as $choice){
            $id = $field["id"] . '_' . $choice_id++;
            $field_value = !empty($choice["value"]) || rgar($field, "enableChoiceValue") ? $choice["value"] : $choice["text"];
            $checked = rgar($choice,"isSelected") ? "checked='checked'" : "";
            $tabindex = GFCommon::get_tabindex();

            $input = sprintf("<input name='input_%d' type='radio' value='%s' %s id='choice_%s' $tabindex $logic_event />", $field["id"], esc_attr($field_value), $checked, $id);
            $choices .= sprintf("<li class='gchoice_$id'><label for='choice_%s'>%s %s</label></li>", $id, $input, $choice["text"]);

            $count++;
        }

    }

    return $choices;
}
```